# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n(1+n^2)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form

How would you recommend me to tackle the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n(1+n^2)}$$?
Can we possibly express it in terms of known constants? What do you think about it?

Comment: It can be expressed in terms of the Lerch transcendent, incomplete beta functions, or hypergeometric series.

Answer (score 3):

You may recall the [Lerch transcendent](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.14) function
$$
\Psi(z,s,a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{(a+k)^s}
$$
and use
$$
\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n+i}-\frac{1}{n-i}\right)
$$
to get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n(1+n^2)}=-1-\Im \: \Psi\left(\frac12,1,i\right)
$$
which gives your series in terms of a known special function.

**Maybe someday** we will be able to say something deeper...

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica yields

```
Sum[1/(2^n (1 + n^2)), {n, \[Infinity]}]
```

giving $$\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{4}\right) (\, _2F_1(1,1;2-i;-1)+i \, _2F_1(1,1;2+i;-1))\approx0.318057$$
where $_2F_1$ is the confluent 2F1 hypergeometric function, which agrees with numerical summation.

As for how one could obtain this result by hand, perhaps another user could supply that answer?

Comment: Note that $_2 F_1(\ldots)$ is _not_ a known constant ($\pm0$)

Comment: @AlexR: True, but maybe the Mathematica output will provide clues for someone who knows how to manipulate it into an expression involving known constants.

Answer (score 0):

The most compact form I was able to specify is
$$3\,\Re\left({_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c 1,1 \\ 1+i\end{array}\middle|\,-1\right)\right) - \Im\left({_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c 1,1 \\ 1+i\end{array}\middle|\,-1\right)\right) - 2\,\Re\left({_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c 1,1 \\ i\end{array}\middle|\,-1\right)\right).$$

By the way for the numerical value [*ISC* gives back](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.318057480653625305231012580794578312380021751755035017439972&lookup_type=simple) the sum.